# Python Program rsync

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am struggling to make a program on Python (Ubuntu) "To get a file from a directly connected Linux machine without prompting for Password"

Right now I am using this command on python but wanna put password in advance so it will not prompt me for password.

```
import os
os.system("echo 'hello world'")
os.system("rsync -rav pi@192.168.2.34:python ~/")
```

IP Address of Other Linux Machine is: **192.168.2.34**
Password is: **raspberry**
Hostname: **pi**

Comment: you may be able to do it with subprocess

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Cunningham Can you again review my question I just edit it.
Thank You

Comment: Consider exchanging private keys, so that the password prompt doesn't even show up?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Can you please guide me how can I do it in convenient way

Comment: try [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

Comment: You can run rsync on either machine [as a daemon](http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2011/01/running-rsync-as-a-daemon.html) and use a command like `rsync -rav rsync://pi@192.168.2.34/python ~/`. This may or may not be practical in your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by `exchanging private keys`. This way you can get a file from a directly connected Linux machine without prompting for Password. Here are the steps to exchange private keys:

1. Execute command `ssh-keygen` on your Ubuntu terminal.
2. Keep on pressing enter until something like this shows up:

   ```
   The key's randomart image is:
   +--[ RSA 2048]----+
   |          .    .*|
   |         . +   +o|
   |          + * + .|
   |         o E * * |
   |        S + + o +|
   |         o o o   |
   |          . . .  |
   |                 |
   |                 |
   +-----------------+
   ```
3. After that execute `ssh-copy-id pi@192.168.2.34` and enter password i.e., `raspberry`, if that is the password for the other machine.

Now execute python script as normal and it wont prompt for password.

```
import os
os.system("echo 'hello world'")
os.system("rsync -rav pi@192.168.2.34:python ~/")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following using pexpect and subprocess, the pexpect should definitely work, subprocess I am not sure:

```
cmd = "rsync -rav pi@192.168.2.34:python ~/"
from pexpect import *

run(cmd,events={'(?i)password':'your_password\r'})

from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
cmd = "rsync -rav pi@192.168.2.34:python ~/"
proc = Popen(cmd.split(),stdin=PIPE)
proc.stdin.write('your_pass\r')
proc.stdin.flush()
```

If you don't have pexpect installed use `pip install pexpect`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a private network (it should be as addresses are 192.168.*.*), and if you trust all IP addresses on that network (means that no unauthorized user can spool an IP), you can also use host based authentication.

Extract from man page for ssh (I assume you use it as the underlying protocol for rsync) :

*Host-based authentication works as follows: If the machine the user logs in from is listed in /etc/hosts.equiv or /etc/shosts.equiv on the remote machine, and the user names are the same on both sides, or if the files ~/.rhosts or ~/.shosts exist in the user's home directory on the remote machine and contain a line containing the name of the client machine and the name of the user on that machine, the user is considered for login.*

That is you put in `pi` home directory a file `.shosts` containing one line

```
name_or_ip_address_of_source_machine    user_name_on_source_machine
```

if the file already exists, just add that line.

But ... you must understand that as for BHAT IRSHAD's solution, it implies that you are now allowed to pass any command on dest machine as user pi without password.